# How to set Chart.js axis minumum to 0?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I've been having trouble with chart.js recently. My graphs are setting the minimum value on the Y axis to the same value as the minimum value in my dataset. As a result this value is not appearing on the graph even though the value is above zero. I have tried to set a new min as explained in the chart.js docs but it doesn't work. Can anyone see my problem or another way to achieve this possibly? Thanks

```
    let carsByYear = document.getElementById('carsByYear');

    let carsByYearChart = new Chart(carsByYear, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: [
                <?php
                foreach ($carsByYear as $p) {
                    if ($p['price'] > 0) {
                        echo "{$p['year']},";
                    }
                }
                ?>
            ],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Number of cars available by year',
                data: [
                    <?php
                    foreach ($carsByYear as $p) {
                        if ($p['price'] > 0) {
                            echo "{$p['total']},";
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                ],
                backgroundColor: ['#01487C', '#008EC8', '#01487C', '#008EC8', '#01487C',
                    '#008EC8', '#01487C', '#008EC8', '#01487C', '#008EC8', '#01487C', '#008EC8',
                    '#01487C', '#008EC8', '#01487C', '#008EC8'
                ],
                borderWidth: 2,
                hoverBorderWidth: 3,
                hoverBorderColor: 'whitesmoke',
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                y: {
                    suggestedMin: 0,
                    suggestedMax: 100
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Found an answer on a youtube tutorial.

```
options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
```